# vertical spacing distribution in CSS grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm new to CSS grid, and I've come across a problem with a layout:
I'd like the paragraph text on the first entry to sit just below the header, but the image on the left which spans both rows is expanding the right hand cells equally, leaving too much space between the header and paragraph.

Is there a way to make sure the first row is sized only to the height of the header, and the paragraph row takes up all remaining space? I'd like to do this using just css ideally.

Normally I would do this with a container div for the header and paragraph, but I'm using css grid to change the source order from the mobile layout, so I don't think a container will work.

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/isaacsgraphic/pen/xyzpmJ)

```css
body {
  background: #444;
}

.chunkheader,
.chunkpara,
.chunkimage {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.chunk {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.chunkimage {
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width:600px) {
  .chunk {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 200px auto;
    grid-column-gap: 20px;
  }
  .chunkimage {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 3;
  }
  .chunkheader {
    grid-column-start: 2;
  }
  .chunkpara {
    grid-column-start: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="chunk">
  <h2 class="chunkheader">Entry one</h2>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/700/?image=571" alt="" class="chunkimage">
  <p class="chunkpara">The A000005 is an Arduino Nanoboard which is a small, breadboard-friendly board based on the ATmega328 (Arduino Nano 3.0) or ATmega168 (Arduino Nano 2.x). It has similar functionality to the Arduino Duemilanove, but in a different package. It lacks
    only a DC power jack and is instead powered through the Mini-B USB connector. The Nano was designed and is being produced by Gravitech.</p>
</div>
<div class="chunk">
  <h2 class="chunkheader">Entry two</h2>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/400/?image=572" alt="" class="chunkimage">
  <p class="chunkpara">The A000005 is an Arduino Nanoboard which is a small, breadboard-friendly board based on the ATmega328 (Arduino Nano 3.0) or ATmega168 (Arduino Nano 2.x). It has similar functionality to the Arduino Duemilanove, but in a different package. It lacks
    only a DC power jack and is instead powered through the Mini-B USB connector. The Nano was designed and is being produced by Gravitech.</p>
</div>
<div class="chunk">
  <h2 class="chunkheader">Entry three</h2>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/400/?image=573" alt="" class="chunkimage">
  <p class="chunkpara">The A000005 is an Arduino Nanoboard which is a small, breadboard-friendly board based on the ATmega328 (Arduino Nano 3.0) or ATmega168 (Arduino Nano 2.x). It has similar functionality to the Arduino Duemilanove, but in a different package. It lacks
    only a DC power jack and is instead powered through the Mini-B USB connector. The Nano was designed and is being produced by Gravitech.</p>
</div>
```

How it looks:
[image]

How I'd like it to look:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify a `grid-template-rows` like below:

```css
body {
  background: #444;
}

.chunkheader,
.chunkpara,
.chunkimage {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.chunk {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.chunkimage {
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width:600px) {
  .chunk {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 200px auto;
    grid-template-rows:auto 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 20px;
  }
  .chunkimage {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 3;
  }
  .chunkheader {
    grid-column-start: 2;
  }
  .chunkpara {
    grid-column-start: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="chunk">
  <h2 class="chunkheader">Entry one</h2>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/700/?image=571" alt="" class="chunkimage">
  <p class="chunkpara">The A000005 is an Arduino Nanoboard which is a small, breadboard-friendly board based on the ATmega328 (Arduino Nano 3.0) or ATmega168 (Arduino Nano 2.x). It has similar functionality to the Arduino Duemilanove, but in a different package. It lacks
    only a DC power jack and is instead powered through the Mini-B USB connector. The Nano was designed and is being produced by Gravitech.</p>
</div>

<div class="chunk">
  <h2 class="chunkheader">Entry two</h2>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/400/?image=572" alt="" class="chunkimage">
  <p class="chunkpara">The A000005 is an Arduino Nanoboard which is a small, breadboard-friendly board based on the ATmega328 (Arduino Nano 3.0) or ATmega168 (Arduino Nano 2.x). It has similar functionality to the Arduino Duemilanove, but in a different package. It lacks
    only a DC power jack and is instead powered through the Mini-B USB connector. The Nano was designed and is being produced by Gravitech.</p>
</div>

<div class="chunk">
  <h2 class="chunkheader">Entry three</h2>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/400/?image=573" alt="" class="chunkimage">
  <p class="chunkpara">The A000005 is an Arduino Nanoboard which is a small, breadboard-friendly board based on the ATmega328 (Arduino Nano 3.0) or ATmega168 (Arduino Nano 2.x). It has similar functionality to the Arduino Duemilanove, but in a different package. It lacks
    only a DC power jack and is instead powered through the Mini-B USB connector. The Nano was designed and is being produced by Gravitech.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I tried so many things to sort this out, but this is exactly what I was looking for.